# Gauss Map and Geodesic Flow

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation, ergodic-theory, geodesic

I was reading chpater (**9**) of the "**Ergodic Theory with a view towards Number Theory**" book by **Manfred Einsiedler** and **Thomas Ward**.

To be more precise, I was trying to understand the connection between the **Gauss Map** and the **Geodesic Flow** as it is illustrated in the Section **6** of the chpater (**9.6 Ergodicity of the Gauss Map**).

To be honest, the idea was not too much clear to me (I did not say that it is not clear at all). Therefore, I am now looking for references that illustrate the connection between the **Gauss Map** and the **Geodesic Flow** is a way that is easier than the one in this chapter.

I would be very grateful if one could suggest some good references.

See pages **317**, **318** and **319**.
[image]
[image]
One of the questions is:

What is the "first" visit of the geodesic flow to the set $\pi(C)$ to consider the next visit?

Comment: You have to make the question self-contained because in its current form it is unanswerable by anybody not familiar with the book you are reading. On the face if it, there is no connection because the geodesic flow is intrinsic to the metric while the Gauss map is extrinsic (depends on the embedding in the Euclidean 3-space).

Comment: In particular, you should define the Gauss map here. I took a quick look at the book, and, from the definition given at the start of 3.2, it does not look to me like the more familiar Gauss map of a hypersurface in Riemannian manifold.

Comment: @Deane it would be much better to take a look at the chapter 9, section 6. If you don't mind.

Comment: I would assume that the Gauss map discussed in 9.6 is the one defined in 3.2. Since I know nothing about this type of Gauss map, I'm of no help here.

Comment: In any case, as @MoisheKohan said, you should provide the definition of a Gauss map and other specifics, so that someone can help you, even if they have no access to the book.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I got your point

Comment: @Deane and yours too

Comment: In case anyone else is curious, this Wikipedia page has the definition of the Gauss map: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction. I had never heard of this before.

Comment: @Deane take a look at the question again, if you don't mind.

Comment: @MoisheKohan take a look at the question again, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have time to check the calculations, but the authors define a certain closed subset $C$ of the unit tangent bundle $X=UT(M)$ (of the modular orbifold). Given a point $v\in C$, the geodesic $c_v$ in $X$ defined by $v$ (so that $c_v(0)=v$) first leaves $C$ at time $t_0\ge 0$, which can be regarded as the end of the  "first visit" of $C$. Formally speaking, $t_0$ is the supremum of all $t\ge 0$ such that $c_v(t)\in C$.

Then there is the smallest $t_1^- >t_0$ such that $c_v(t)\in C$. This is the "next time" $c_v$ visits $C$, more precisely, the first time $c_v$ reenters $C$.

You did not ask, but there will be $t_1^+$, the "end of the 2nd visit," where $t_1^+$ is the supremum of all $\{t \ge t_1^-: c_v(t)\in C\}$. This is the end time of the 2nd visit. And so on.